# Changing data format with before_validation doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, callback

I'm saving some attributes of my model instances as floats, but it's necessary for my app to handle an input from a form with commas instead of points (ex. 10,99 should be saved as 10.99). 
I'm trying to do that with before_validation callbacks, but I can't make it work properly - input with commas can't get through validations, I keep getting price/size2 is not a number error.

```
class Advert < ActiveRecord::Base    

before_validation do
  normalize(self.price) if is_number?(self.price)
  normalize(self.size2) if is_number?(self.size2)
end

validates :price, presence: true, numericality: true
validates :size2, numericality: true

def is_number?(string)
  true if Float(string) rescue false
end

def normalize(number)
  number.to_s.gsub!(',', '.').to_f
end
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I havent tested it but i think you are not actually modifying *price* and *size2* as you are gsub!ing number and not returning the value to the 2 attributes.

what about something like this:

```
class Advert < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_validation :string_to_float

  validates :price, presence: true, numericality: true
  validates :size2, numericality: true

  def is_number?(string)
    true if Float(string) rescue false
  end

  def normalize(number)
    number.to_s.gsub(',', '.').to_f
  end

  def string_to_float
    self.price = normalize(self.price) if is_number?(self.price)
    self.size2 = normalize(self.size2) if is_number?(self.size2)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, that of course was an error, but after fixing it, the format with commas still can't get through validation. The test shows that if the input is '12,2', the saved value is '12.0', so it seems that the input is converted to float before the normalize method is called.

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom setter method instead:

```
class Advert
  def price=(val)
     @price = val.is_a?(Float) ? val : val.to_f  
  end 
end
```

Comment: I'm running `ruby 2.1.5p273` and I don't actually need to replace `,` with `.` when using `.to_f`. One thing to be aware of is that in some locales comma is used to denote thousands: 10,001 (ten thousand one).

Answer (score 0):

As I couldn't handle the decimal delimiter change via rails callbacks, I just wrote a simple jQuery workaround, maybe it'll help someone:

```
normalize_input = ->
  $('form').submit ->
    normalized_price = $('#advert_price').val().replace(',', '.') # advert_price is a form input
    normalized_size2 = $('#size2input').val().replace(',', '.') # just like the size2input
    $('#advert_price').val(normalized_price)
    $('#size2input').val(normalized_size2)
```